# How to change Appendix chapter name

Tags: appendices

I have a long appendix which includes a lot of equations and figures.
My document class is report.
In order to have a separate appendix section, I used:

```
\appendix
\chapter{The first appendix}
```

The outcome shows like this

> Chapter A
>
> The first appendix

How can I change it to:

> Appendix A
>
> The first appendix

I also tried

```
\chapter*{Appendix: The First Appendix}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix: The First Appendix}
```

But in this way, my equation number does not start with A.1. This will not work for me.

Comment: Can you construct a minimal example of what you are doing. If you create a document with `\documentclass{report}`, one chapter, the `\appendix` command and another chapter, the appendix name shows up as you want it, so you must be doing something else. (I also formatted your code.  You can format code by indenting it by 4 spaces, or selecting it and clicking the `{}` icon.)

Comment: Is this problem with the chapter name appearing in the chapter heading or only in the table of contents? As I couldn't reproduce the issue here, besides the minimal working example you should post your preamble, too.

Comment: I think this issue only occurs on old packages. I had the same experience in the past, so update your packages first and let me know.

Answer (score 10):

As xport noted, you probably have an *old* (very old) version of TeX. Newer version don't have this problem. The best solution is to update; you probably have a lot of other since-corrected misfeatures in addition to this one. If you can't update, try the following:

```
\appendix
\renewcommand\chaptername{Appendix}
\chapter{The first appendix}
```

Answer (score 6):

I do not really understand your problem. However, maybe that you are looking fro something like this:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter
\def\setChapterprefix#1{\gdef\@Prefix{#1}}
\setChapterprefix{}
\renewcommand*\l@chapter[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \vskip 1.0em \@plus\p@
    \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode \bfseries
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      \hskip -\leftskip
      \@Prefix 
      #1\nobreak\hfil \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}\par
      \penalty\@highpenalty
    \endgroup
  \fi}
    \makeatother
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \chapter{Introduction to Quantum Electrodynamics}
        \blindtext
    \appendix
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setChapterprefix{Appendix }}
    \chapter{Calculus of Variations}
        \blindtext
    \chapter{Digital Signal Processing}
        \blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great solution! if needed, the chapter name can also be shown, with an `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setChapterprefix{Chapter }}` before the chapters

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code within the chapter not the preamble:

```
\setcounter{chapter}{0}
\appendix
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@chapapp}{Appendix}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 0):

Before starting the chapter that will be your appendix insert the following commands:

```
\renewcommand\chaptername{Appendix}                      % hereafter, chapters are called "Appendix"
\renewcommand\thechapter{\Alph{chapter}}                % chapter number in alph letters
\renewcommand\thesection{\Alph{chapter}.\Roman{section}} % make sections "A.I"
\setcounter{chapter}{0}                                  % start numbering chapters from 1 on again
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a corner case but for me, none of the answers works.
Because I'm using `titlesec` to change all other title formats, the chapter name is fixed by me using `\titleformat` in the preamble.
Adding the following command right before the appendix can change the title name for me

```
\appendix % change numbering
\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\large}{Appendix \thechapter:}{1em}{} % change keyword
\input{../maintext/AppendixA} % load appendix (starting with \chapter)
```