# Adding to the appendix title

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices

What I'm looking to get is the word "ANNEX" prefixing all of my Appendix names, both in the document chapters and in the TOC. Is there a method of adding "Annex" to the name of the appendix chapter so that it looks like:

**ANNEX A Something**

Rather than:

**A Something**

I'm using Memoir, and if I try to use the appendix class as such:

```
\usepackage[titletoc,page]{appendix}
```

I get an `option clash` for appendix.

NB. There's a number of examples of people adding the word "Appendix" to the TOC ([1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49905/word-appendix-in-toc-with-memoir-class), [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60320/memoir-appendix), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690679/add-appendix-before-a-in-thesis-toc), [4](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109904/appendix-with-titletoc-and-memoir)), and the answer may well be contained in these links but my latex-fu is still too underdeveloped to figure out the answer. I tried changing the appendix chapter name as per [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21047/how-to-change-appendix-chapter-name), but this still doesn't insert the name into the chapter.

Comment: For future reference, it would be super helpful if you could just mock up a simple, compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) so that community members can just copy-and-paste and have *something* to work with. It may seem trivial to you, but those who frequently help don't want to recreate a platform, from scratch, with even the simplest of questions...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To your document preamble, add

```
\renewcommand{\appendixname}{ANNEX}% Change "chapter name" for Appendix chapters
\renewcommand*{\cftappendixname}{ANNEX~}% Addition to chapter number
```

Here is a mimal document that showcases the output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}% http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir
\renewcommand*{\appendixname}{ANNEX}% Change "chapter name" for Appendix chapters
\renewcommand*{\cftappendixname}{ANNEX~}% Addition to chapter number
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{A chapter}
\appendix
\chapter{An appendix}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I realised that using \chapterstyle{section} was removing the `Annex` text, changing \chapterstyle{} back to another style with the chapter names in it has added the Annex back in. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @mrmagooey: Another testament to providing small examples that replicate your current behaviour...

Comment: My thoughts exactly, MWE's from here on in